# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable (+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT))

Tags: python, django

here is my django project's urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='home'),
    path('abouts/about/',views.about,name='about'),
    path('abouts/contact/',views.contact,name='contact'),
    path('orders/cart/',views.cart,name='cart'),
    path('shops/dashboard/',views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
    path('shops/orders/',views.orders,name='orders'),
    path('shops/checkout/',views.checkout,name='checkout'),
] +static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and the part of settings.py where I defined media url and media root

```
import os
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     BASE_DIR/ 'static',
     
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

but the server says

```
ile "C:\Users\ITS\Desktop\e-com\commerce\shop\urls.py", line 15, in <module>
    ] +static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I do this always but now it showing me this. thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to replace `from django.conf.urls import static` to `from django.conf.urls.static import static`in your Django project's `urls.py`. Pay attention to details.